# OpenSSL on WampServer

Tags: php, wampserver

I have installed and followed all the step in creating an  using Openssl but when I open localhost as https the browser says the connection is not secure or brings out privacy.

Kindly let me know what am doing wrong? How can one make it https and bring the green lock?

Answer (score 1):

You did everything right but the browser doesn't know your certificate.

The browser will warn you everytime he gets a certificate signed by an authority he doesn't know. That DOESN'T mean that you did something wrong.

You can add your certificate as trustworthy (i.e. add an exception for your specific certificate) in the browser and everything will function as it would with a certificate from a trusted certificate authority (e.g. Comodo, RapidSSL, Symantec, etc)